# Is there any direct reference to the descriptions of all 9 Avatars of Hanuman?

Tags: hanuman

I tried and found only Avtar names and there is not much information avaialable in the internet. Are there any Stotras or scriptures which explains the forms and Avtars in detail?

Example: Dwatrishathi Ayudha Hanuman, what all does the god hold in each of the hands? And, what does each hand sign signify?